# How to resize images to fit on left half screen when selected and show list view on second half?

Tags: android, image, android-layout

I have been trying to achieve this for the last 20 days but I'm not able to find any solution. I have to show two columns of images which will be fetched from a URL. When any image is selected, all images should be resized and come on the left half. At the same time on the right half I have to show the details of the selected image with transition effects at the time of image resizing and second half details coming.

Below is the screenshot of both screens. I am able to create the first screen, but I don't know how to achieve the second one.

[image: screen1]

[image: screen 2]